# imacros - how to get content of external file php

Tags: php, get, external, imacros

I am new in iMacros and I really need your help.
esotu writing a iMacros script and did not want to leave the code accessible to any user changes and maintenance work gives me later.

I need to get all my imacro code from an external php file of my website .

the idea is that the macro has only the url where the php file, and the contents of this file to run when the macro is run .

so far I have this code here, and I can not do imacro read the contents of the php file:

```
VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX


SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1

SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30

SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST

SET !DATASOURCE http://www. site .com/todocodigoaqui.php

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1

SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !TODOCODIGOAQUI URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

thanks

```
TAB T=1  
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
```

Answer (score 1):

The variant for Firefox 'iMacros':

```
const L = "\n";
var M = "TAB T=1" + L;
M += "TAB OPEN" + L;
M += "TAB T=2" + L;
M += "URL GOTO=http://www. site .com/todocodigoaqui.php" + L;
M += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + L;
M += "TAB CLOSE" + L;
iimPlayCode(M);
iimPlayCode(iimGetExtract());
```

---

You can get the contents of your php-file in this way:

```
' ...
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://www. site .com/todocodigoaqui.php
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE
'PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
'...
```

If you use JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox, run the extracted macro with `iimPlayCode(iimGetExtract())` .

Comment: hello friend thanks for the answer.

I tried from the morning and so far I could not. I sounded new to programming .

mind to help me a little more? please. I hope soon porder help you in any way ...

what I need is to run all the code that has the file.php in iMacros ...

example :

I do not know what to do when I get the contents of the file ...
PROMPT { { ! }} EXTRACT

Thank you so much...

Comment: Hello. Let your script have the name with ‘.js’ extension. See the updated answer and try the variant for Firefox ‘iMacros’.